# Python issue with lists (API/JSON)

Tags: python, api

I'm having trouble with my lists in python.
I'm trying to grab data inside of the JSON I have pulled with requests.
Here's a snippet of something I'm trying to pull from:
https://euw1.api.riotgames.com/lol/match/v3/matches/3884275290?api_key=RGAPI-43936bd4-d025-4ead-b1cf-8a87d8598135

(Don't worry, the API key isn't my development one)

Here's the code I'm having issues with:

`print gameInUse['participants']['participantId'][participantIdList[5]]['championId']`

The error that I'm getting is mainly
TypeError: list indices must be integers, not str

Which I don't understand.

I understand that one part of this must be wrong as one of indices must be incorrect or I'm missing one, I just can't figure out where or which.

Comment: `gameInUse['participants']` is a list so you might want to have `gameInUse['participants'][0].....`. also there's no `participantIdList`. You need to work a bit more on your understanding of the *json* structure. Maybe with an online viewer?

Comment: in your code,  `gameInUse['participants']` is a list whose indices are 0,1,2,3 etc.. while you are trying with a string. ..  find some GOOD resources to learn Python

Comment: participantIdList was to be assumed, I thought programmers who criticise understanding could assume one line wasn't my entire code? I suppose not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that gameInUse is the JSON returned in that API, the problem is that `gameInUse['participants']` is a list of participants, so you need an integer to search by index.

It looks like the participants are listed starting with an index of 1, so you could use:

`gameInUse['participants'][0]` for the first participant. To get their championId, you'd use:

`print gameInUse['participants'][0]['championId']`

I use [this site](https://jsonformatter.org/json-pretty-print) to help me visualize JSON better.

Comment: @AnnikaZero No problem. SO isn't always brand-new-beginner-friendly just because these kinds of questions are mistakes more experienced developers might make, but will catch immediately. You'll get there. Just remember to figure out what the error is trying to tell you. Debugging is 80% of coding.

Answer (score 0):

if you check the structure of the Json object you can see that the value of `gameInUse['participants']` is type `list` not `dict`, so you must place an integer in order to obtain an element of the list, not a string (the key of a dictionary).

So, en example of it could be `gameInUse['participants'][0].`

Take the time to read the Json Object and understand the value types.